# Pandas, renaming a duplicate column inside a groupby call

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas to count up an element of a dataframe. 
My Data looks something like

```
A    B    C    
001  003  1
001  003  1
001  003  0 
...
```

I'm using the code:

```
exampleDataFrame = exampleDataFrame.groupby(['A','B','C'])['C'].size()
```

Where C can only be a 1, or a 0. (I need to see how many 1's and 0's appear in C per A and B).

This gives me a result such as follows:

```
A    B    C    C
001  003  1    2    (There were 2 '1's in C for columns A and B)
001  003  0    1
...
```

But now I need to rename the 4th column ('C') to a more unique name, such as 'D'. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename Dataframe column based on column index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41685917/rename-dataframe-column-based-on-column-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try, `rename` the series after the groupby then reset_index to get dataframe:

```
df.groupby(['A','B','C'])['C'].size().rename('D').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  3  0  1
1  1  3  1  2
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!